# "Prepare" SQL insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a file upload function on my site that is executed right after a post has been submitted.

The only problem with this is that if there's an error with the file upload after the post has been submitted, such as if the file is too large, the post will still have been submitted.

Currently I have to delete the inserted post if the file upload fails, but I figure there's probably a better solution to this.

The code looks something like this:

```
$query=$con->query('INSERT INTO `posts` (`user`,`comment`) VALUES("'.$user->id.'","'.$comment.'")'); //Submit post
$postID = $con->insert_id; //This variable is needed for the file upload

if (empty($error)){  //proceed with file upload

//.....

if (empty($error))
     $con->query('DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = "'.$postID.'" LIMIT 1'); //Delete post if file error
}else{
     $con->query('UPDATE `posts` SET `image` =".$imageID." WHERE `id` = "'.$postID.'" LIMIT 1'); //
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just check the size of the file before?

Comment: SQL injection is not your friend.  And you are open to it doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you could call `START TRANSACTION` before the insert and `COMMIT` on success, or `ROLLBACK` on error.

And as durbnpoisn pointed out, you should check your queries for SQL injection.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem with this is that if there's an error with the file
>   upload after the post has been submitted, such as if the file is too
>   large, the post will still have been submitted.

Yes a form will always be submitted no matter if there's an error or not.
The better solution here would be turning your task into small ones. So in words - do write an image path into a table in case there's no error.

Turning that words into a code leads to something like this:

```
<?php

// If there were not errors during form submission
// As you might know 0 means there are absolutely no errors
if ($_FILES['field_name']['error']) == 0) {

  $db->insert(....);

  $id = $db->getLastId();

  $uploader->upload($_FILES, $id);

} else {

   // Just display errors and don't do anything here
}
```

This way you absolute guarantee that your thing will be inserted into a table in case there absolutely are no errors, so that another queries are not needed at all.